# alsamixer doesn't save changes on exit

Tags: sound, alsa

My system keeps going to the wrong device for sound output. When I tell alsamixer that I want the generic device, and then exit alsamixer, it doesn't save the change. By that I mean that if I open alsamixer again, my changes haven't been made.

I have tried adding myself to the audio group and I have tried opening another terminal and running alsactl store but I can't get it to store.

I have generated a settings file with alsactl and edited it remove the unwanted devices and then run alsactl restore from the settings file and it has no effect.

How can I get alsamixer to save the settings? How can I get rid of the devices it see that are actually incapable of playing sound (such as m video card or my microphone)

Comment: can u tell us your OS and that config file u wrote.. kinda impossible to help u out having nothing to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use pavucontrol to unmute line out. alsamixer didn't work.

Comment: Yes, if you use pulseaudio, it will override your ALSA settings.